# Create custom adapter for TwoWayView

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I needed to make a horizontal listview, after searching I found a solution which is TwoWayView.

The "textview" [example](https://guides.codepath.com/android/implementing-a-horizontal-listview-guide) on the internet works find for me but I need it an ImageView item not TextView so I created an adapter:

```
public class Custom_Supermarket_Adapter_2 extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
private Context context;
private Integer[] imagelist;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private View view;
private DatabaseHandler dbhandler;
private ImageView imageview;
private int resource;
public Custom_Supermarket_Adapter_2(Context context, int resource, Integer[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.imagelist = objects;
    this.resource = resource;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
      view = mInflater.inflate(resource, null);
    }else{
        view = convertView;
    }
    imageview = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.customimageview);
    imageview.setImageResource(imagelist[position]);

    imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("POSITION CLICKED",Integer.toString(position));
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

And I call it in the class like this:

```
/*These are the array of the image I want to be displayed*/
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.citimart,R.drawable.coopmart,R.drawable.lottemart,R.drawable.maximark,R.drawable.metro
};

Custom_Supermarket_Adapter_2 aItems = new Custom_Supermarket_Adapter_2(this,R.layout.simple_list_item, mThumbIds);
    TwoWayView lvTest = (TwoWayView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    lvTest.setAdapter(aItems);
```

This is my `simple_list_item` xml file

```
 <ImageView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customimageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

And this is the main layout that contains the horizontal listview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lvItems"
    style="@style/TwoWayView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    tools:context=".Listing_items"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:id="@+id/gridView_main"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the app, I only see the empty `TwoWayView`, no image is displayed, I tried to tap on everywhere inside that TwoWayView, The logcat shows "POSITION CLICKED 0", tapped everywhere and just position 0. Looks like only the first image is processed but somehow it cannot be rendered. Am I missing a loop or something to make it show all images? And did I `findviewbyID` the wrong one?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I found something wrong for your getView methods. Maybe you try to use ViewHolder Pattern. This code will be work with your code.

```
ViewHolder holder;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(resource, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.imageview.setImageResource(imagelist[position]);
holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("POSITION CLICKED",Integer.toString(position));
    }
});
return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
          imageview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customimageview);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to override 3 methods:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imagelist.length;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Integer getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

They started to show up all items.

For the "empty" part of the problem, it was because the pictures I want to display have different resolution, I just resize all of them to one single resolution and they show up.

Thank you all for stopping by.